# Why cant I access these variables in my anonymous inner class?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Can anyone tell me why I can't access address, latitude and longitude variables in the `onClick()` method of `dialog.setPositiveButton()` of `onTouchEvent`?

```
class MapOverlayClass extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
{

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
Context context;

public MapOverlayClass(Drawable drawable)
{
    super(boundCenterBottom(drawable));
}

public MapOverlayClass(Drawable defaultMarker,Context context)
{
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    this.context=context;
}

//called after we add the overlays to the overlay ArrayList and call populate()

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)
{
    return overlayList.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size()
{
    return overlayList.size();
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
{
    overlayList.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int i)
{
    OverlayItem overlay = overlayList.get(i);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(overlay.getTitle());
    builder.setMessage(overlay.getSnippet());
    builder.show();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapview)
{
    if(event.getAction()==1)
    {
        GeoPoint geopoint = mapview.getProjection().fromPixels((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context,Locale.ENGLISH);

        Double latitude=null,longitude=null;
        latitude = geopoint.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
        longitude = geopoint.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

        String address = "";

        try
        {

            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            String featurename = list.get(0).getFeatureName();
            String countryname = list.get(0).getCountryName();
            String adminarea = list.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String premises = list.get(0).getPremises();



            if(featurename!=null)
            {
                address = address+" "+featurename;
            }               
            if(adminarea!=null)
            {
                address = address+" "+adminarea;
            }
            if(premises!=null)
            {
                address = address+" "+premises;
            }
            if(countryname!=null)
            {
                address = address+" "+countryname;
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Location Alarm");
            dialog.setMessage("Do you want to set alarm at this location "+address+"?");

            dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent  intent = new Intent(context,Fill_Information.class);
                    intent.putExtra("address", address);  //HERE
                    intent.putExtra("address", longitude);   //HERE
                    intent.putExtra("address", latitude);  //HERE
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Address not found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error ? Did you try to set them as final variables ?

Comment: but i am appending the address variable.So how can i make it final?

Comment: final worked for latitude and longitude but not address

Comment: Because you're modifying adress in the if statement. Declare a new final variable that receive adress just befre setting the positive button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because onClick is declared as an Anonymous inner class

```
final String maddress = address;
final double lat = latitude;
final double lon = longitude;
dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent  intent = new Intent(context,Fill_Information.class);
                intent.putExtra("address", maddress);  //HERE
                intent.putExtra("latitude", lat);   //HERE
                intent.putExtra("longitude", lon);  //HERE
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

The keys for the putExtra have to been unique otherwise you will find only the lastValue you putted inside